# How to set different widths for date-select?

Tags: html, css, date

I have variations of this line in different places:

`<%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-pick', id: 'goal' %>`

I tried to change the width by making different id's for `select` or `date-select` or `date-pick` but to no avail.

Here are some examples from my stylesheet:

```
select.goal {
  width: 29.6%;
  color: green;
}

#goal.date-select {
  width: 29.6%;
  color: green;
}

.select {
 #goal {
  width: 29.6%;
  color: green;
}
}
```

Only setting the width via `.select { width: 29.6%; }` works but then it affects all my date-selects. What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

These were self-generated by the system somehow. Saw it via chrome inspect. Copy and pasted into css file and made appropriate adjustments:

```html
#goal_deadline_1i {
  width: 29.6%;
  color: green;
}

#goal_deadline_2i {
  width: 29.6%;
  color: green;
}

#goal_deadline_3i {
  width: 29.6%;
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this line:

```
<%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-pick', id: 'goal' %>
```

Yo can do:

```
#goal {
    width: 29.6%;
    color: green;
}
```

You can use `#gloa.date-pick` or `.date-pick#goal` but assuming the IDs are unique it'll be overdoing it.

Just remember the **order does matter**. If you do like this:

```
.class1.class2 {
    background-color: green;
}
.class1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

all `.class1` elements will have blue background, even `.class2.class1` cause it'll be overridden, so if that's the case do it like:

```
.class1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.class1.class2 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks samurai! I had tried `#goal {
    width: 29.6%;
    color: green;
}` but that didn't work with `<%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-pick', id: 'goal' %>`

Comment: Did you check that you weren't overriding it afterwards? Can you show a live demo?

Comment: Then when I inspect the element there is no sign of `date-pick` or the id `goal`  @samurai

Comment: I got the answer, but I marked your's right because you have the generally more useful answer :)